# Configuration SharePoint 2019

Tags: sharepoint-server

[image]Hi All,

I have a problem when I get to step 4 of the sharepoint configuration.

Can someone help me solve this?

Attached is a capture of the error

Answer (score 0):

Can you find the file "WebServices" which does not exist under that path? Does your account have permission on that file? Can you find more related clues in the logs?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check the directory

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\14.0\WebServices
```

permission and disable the firewall. After that, you can try to run SharePoint 2019 Configuration Wizard

Second, did the SharePoint Prerequisites installed without any problem ?

Comment: Hi AIMEN,


Thank you for your solution I check it now.


Yes SharePoint prerequisites were successfully installed

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have all adiministrator priviledge to install sharepoint on windows Server
during the installation of sharepoint you should specify each services with his own Service Account